# SQLAlchemy ORM: Polymorphic Single Table Inheritance, with fallback to parent class if "polymorphic_identity" is not found

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, single-table-inheritance

Using Python 3.5 and SQLAlchemy 1.0.14 (ORM).

I have a table of items declared as such:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    # other non relevant attributes
```

My Items can be of many different types, the type identifier being stored in `type`.
For a few of those objects types, I need to have specific methods or attributes available.

To achieve that I tried to use single table inheritance with several SpecialisedItem as subclass of Item:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, index=True)
    # other non relevant attributes

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }

class SpecialisedItem(Base):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'specialitem',
    }

    def specialised_method(self):
        return "I am special"
```

Now when I load my items, I'd want all specialised items (having `type=='specialitem'`) to be loaded as such, while any other type value would result in the parent class `Item` being loaded.
That doesn't work, I get `AssertionError: No such polymorphic_identity 'normal' is defined` when loading the items.

I would like to avoid creating inherited classes that do nothing just to cover all possible `type` values, instead having "unmapped" `type` falling back to the parent class `Item`.

Is there any way to achieve that effect ?

Minimal test case for reference:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer, String


Base = declarative_base()

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, index=True)
    # other non relevant attributes

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }

class SpecialisedItem(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'special',
    }

    specialAttribute = Column(String)

    def specialised_method(self):
        return "I am special"


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.add(Item(type='normal'))
session.add(Item(type='special'))
session.commit()
# loading only specialized items works
for item in session.query(Item).filter_by(type="special"):
    print(item.specialised_method())

# loading other items fails
for item in session.query(Item):
    print(item.type)
```

Thanks,

Guillaume

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reusable decorator solution, based on [@r-m-n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5341877/r-m-n) answer. Custom class is also replaced with `collections.defaultdict` that actually does same thing.

```
def receive_mapper_configured(mapper, class_):
    mapper.polymorphic_map = defaultdict(lambda: mapper, mapper.polymorphic_map)
    # to prevent 'incompatible polymorphic identity' warning, not necessary
    mapper._validate_polymorphic_identity = None


def polymorphic_fallback(mapper_klass):
    event.listens_for(mapper_klass, 'mapper_configured')(receive_mapper_configured)
    return mapper_klass
```

Then in your code you can just add this decorator to base classes:

```
@polymorphic_fallback
class Item:
    ...

class SpecificItem(Item):
    ...
```

Answer (score 12):

A mapping of “polymorphic identity” identifiers to Mapper instances is stored in the [polymorphic_map](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_map) dict. You can create custom `polymorphic_map` that will return parent class mapper for undefined polymorphic identities.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import event

Base = declarative_base()

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, index=True)
    # other non relevant attributes

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }

class SpecialisedItem(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'special',
    }

    specialAttribute = Column(String)

    def specialised_method(self):
        return "I am special"

#http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.mapper_configured
@event.listens_for(Item, 'mapper_configured')
def receive_mapper_configured(mapper, class_):    
    mapper.polymorphic_map = defaultdict(lambda: mapper, mapper.polymorphic_map)

    # to prevent 'incompatible polymorphic identity' warning, not mandatory
    mapper._validate_polymorphic_identity = None

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.add(Item(type='normal'))
session.add(Item(type='special'))
session.commit()
# loading only specialized items works
for item in session.query(Item).filter_by(type="special"):
    print(item.specialised_method())

# loading other items fails
for item in session.query(Item):
    print(item.type)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! If you don't mind, I updated your response code to be working directly. You'll gain the reward.